# Passing "extra" arguments to a function stored in a variable - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript, I'm self-teaching, so this might be an obvious area, but no matter how I phrase the question I can't really seem to get my head around this one issue. At the moment I'm reading through http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter6.html (which was on mozilla's MDN). I've come across this a couple of times now, I would just like a simple break down if possible.

```
function negate(func) {
  return function(x) {
    return !func(x);
  };
}
var isNotNaN = negate(isNaN);
show(isNotNaN(NaN));
```

I don't understand how at the very last step isNotNaN (a variable) is passing an 'extra argument' (NaN) to the function stored in isNotNaN (negate(isNaN). "show(isNotNaN(NaN));"

I came across this same problem when the concept of enclosure was trying to be explained. But I don't get where this argument "NaN" is *going* in the above function, as it seems to me like the last statement ends up something like:

```
show(negate(isNaN, NaN));
```

I would be happy to provide more details. This concept of passing an extra argument to a variable already holding a function with an argument confuses the hell out of me!

Comment: "as it seems to me like the last statement ends up something like: `show(negate(isNaN, NaN));`". I would say `show(negate(isNaN)(NaN))`. It's not a matter of passing extra arguments, rather passing them to different closures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no "extra" argument.  The `negate()` function itself returns a function defined as a function expression, which can then be called with any number of original (not extra) arguments passed.  A closure is used for the returned function to keep a reference to `isNaN` as `func`.

```
var isNotNaN = negate(isNaN);
```

At this point, `isNotNaN` contains a reference to the function

```
function(x) {
    return !func(x);
};
```

Again, `func` here refers to the `isNaN` argument passed to the `negate` function, which is the immediate parent in the scope chain.  The result is similar, but not the same as

```
var isNotNaN = function (x) {
    return !isNaN(x);
};
```

The reason it is not the same is, if we change the value of `isNaN`, the behaviour of this function will change.  In the example you posted, however, the value of `func` is equal to the original value of `isNaN` and cannot be changed by anything outside of its scope thanks to the closure.

Essentially, you can pass in any function and get a new function that returns the negated result of the original function in return.  For example:

```
var isNotArray = negate(Array.isArray);
isNotArray(12);
//-> true
```

Comment: Excellent! I understand now a bit more when you say that isNotNaN evaluates to (something very similar to) the enclosed function. Also @Johan helped with his foobar function, however I see that in Johans final statement, rather than assigning a value to the argument through fooRef, he seems to assign two separate arguments to straight to foo: "foo(1)(2)"  I presume here in his example the 1 assigns to (x) and the 2 assigns to (y)? If this is correct, is this not a better method than assigning foo(1) to fooRef then passing (2) to fooRef? Or is there something with closures here I'm missing?

Comment: @Bluey: you seem like you've just about got it :-) Neither method is necessarily better, they both have the same effect.  You could say assigning the return value of `foo(1)` to `fooRef` is more readable, especially in cases where `foo()` might take a large number of arguments or a function itself as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, `negate(isNaN)` simply return a function to the variable `isNotNaN`. This function take a parameter (named `x` in your case), then execute the function `isNaN` on the parameter before negating it and returning the result.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this example can clear some things out for you regarding closures:

```
function foo(x){

    function bar(y){
        return x+y;
    }

    return bar;
}

var fooRef = foo(1); // fooRef references foo() with x set to 1

console.log(fooRef(2), foo(1)(2)); // 3, 3
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ePwy8/